# MAUI: NullReferenceException when DisplayAlert in Android Emulator

Tags: nullreferenceexception, maui, android-debug, displayalert

I have a .NET MAUI project and just want to display an alert. This already worked well, but in some cases it throws me a NullRefereceException. The Code is:

```
private async void Info_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Title", "Text", "OK");
}
```

I totally have no clue, what the problem is. The stack trace is:
[image]

It seems it's a problem of the Android debugger/emulator, because with my local Android device, everything works fine...

Thank you for helping :)

Comment: My bet is Application.Current==null and you are calling this earlier than that was populated

Comment: Whenever you get an exception you don't understand, wrap the code in `try .. catch`. Running under debugger, this should make it easier to get a *useful* stack trace, from the exception in the catch block. Presumably, either `Application.Current` or `Application.Current.MainPage` are still null. Which you could also see by adding some test code before that line:  `if (Application.Current == null) {};  if (Application.Current.MainPage == null) {};` With appropriate newlines, so you can put breakpoints on both `{}` lines.

Comment: If only have this problem with the Android emulator. Everything works fine on the local android device. I tried to wrap this line with a try-catch, but the debugger will not execute the catch area, the whole application crashes before. I also added a check, if Application.Current or Application.Current.MainPage is null. Neither is in emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set the `MainPage` in constructor before it is assigned to the `MainPage` property of your App. Otherwise, when using the `App.Current.MainPage` before then, it might throw a `NullReferenceException`.

As an alternative workaround, you can refer to the snippets below:

```
      public static Page rootPage { get; set; } 
      public App()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new MainPage();
            App.rootPage = MainPage;
      }
```

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     await App.rootPage.DisplayAlert("Title", "Text", "OK");
}
```

Comment: I also tried this. But unfortunately without any success. I get the same result - the whole application crashes. No chance for catching the exception...

Comment: What if you use `await DisplayAlert("Title", "Text", "OK");` directly, will it throw a NullRefereceException?

Comment: Then i get error "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'"

Comment: You may need to warp the alert in `await Task.Run(async() =>
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Title", "Text", "OK");
    });

});` from the main thread. BTW, what the API version of your Android Emulator?